# php add items using an multi dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have multi-dimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10184            
            [user_tags] => tag1
         )
)
```

how do i add more 'user_tags' with comma seperated in an array using php

Thanks

Comment: How do i add more tags like this eg,tag1,tag2,tag3....

Comment: What should the result be? Do you want more array entries or just set `user_tags` to this comma-separated list?

Answer (score 3):

```
 $arr[0]['user_tag'] .= ','.$valueToAdd;
```

or

```
$arr[0]['user_tag'] .= ','.implode(',', $valueToAdd); // if its an array
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add something to your 'user_tags' like this :

```
$myarray[0]['user_tags'] = 'whatever';
```

If you have an array of tags like this, you can add it like that :

```
$tags = array('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4');
$myarray[0]['user_tags'] = implode(', ', $tags);
```

But in this case, it is maybe better to store the array directly like said in another comment.

If you want to just add one tag :

```
$myarray[0]['user_tags'] .= ', '.$mytag;
```

Answer (score 2):

As a hint, I wouldn't store the usertags in comma separated style, but rather in another array, so that `$myArray['user_tags'] = array('tag1, 'tag2', 'tag3', ...);`.

You can then translate between array and csv like this:

```
$myArray['user_tags_csv'] = implode(',', $myArray['user_tags']);
$myArray['user_tags'] = explode(',', $myArray['user_tags_csv']);
```

This makes it easier to search the tags for existing ones before you append one.

I use this a lot (esp. with user tags or flags) in connection with an SQL database. With different separators (e.g. ',' ';' '|') I even create hierarchical csv strings which translate into multi-dimensional arrays.

Pro-tip: Store the tags in an associative array like `{'tag1'='tag1', 'tag2'='tag2'}`, create it with

```
$myArray['user_tags'] = array_combine(explode(',', $myArray['user_tags_csv']), explode(',', $myArray['user_tags_csv']);
```

Then you can use `array_key_exists()` as well as `array_search()` and many other neat things. I use that a lot.